# What is the postfix equivelant of exim -bt test@example.com

Tags: command-line, postfix

With exim I can do a "blind test" of an address from the command line.

`exim -bt test@example.com
test@example.com
  router = dnslookup, transport = remote_smtp
  host example.com [2001:db8::1946]
  host example.com [127.0.0.1]`

This tells me what exim thinks of an address and what it *would* try to do with an email with that address, (without creating a message).

How do I do this with postfix?

Comment: Is `sendmail -bv` what you are looking for?

Comment: Not on my server, (where postfix is working with my domains). `# sendmail -bv test@example.com
Mail Delivery Status Report will be mailed to <root>.
# sendmail -bv potus@whitehouse.gov
Mail Delivery Status Report will be mailed to <root>.
`